# Python3: Add to dictionaries in list, based on other dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I am trying to learn / teach myself Python3 and I'm working on reformatting scraped web data.

**Input is a list of dictionaries:**

```
[{'name' : 'Anna', 'gender': "f", 'ID': 512128, 'age' : 28}, 
 {'name' : 'Barney', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 012428, 'age' : 29},
 {'name' : 'Cesar', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 032536, 'age' : 57}]
```

I would like to achieve a list of dictionaries with every dictionary having an additional field names 'colleagues', which contains the information of the *other* dictionaries in the list.

**Desired output:**

```
[{'name' : 'Anna', 'gender': "f", 'ID': 512128, 'age' : 28, 'colleagues' : [{'name' : 'Barney', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 012428, 'age' : 29}, {'name' : 'Cesar', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 032536, 'age' : 57}]}, 
 {'name' : 'Barney', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 012428, 'age' : 29, 'colleagues' : [{'name' : 'Anna', 'gender': "f", 'ID': 512128, 'age' : 28}, {'name' : 'Cesar', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 032536, 'age' : 57}]},
 {'name' : 'Cesar', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 032536, 'age' : 57, 'colleagues' : [{'name' : 'Anna', 'gender': "f", 'ID': 512128, 'age' : 28},  {'name' : 'Barney', 'gender': "m", 'ID': 012428, 'age' : 29}]}]
```

As you can tell, I am new to python but understand simple comprehension and for loops.. etc. I spent the last night with all possible attempts and very nested loop structures - which were causing infinite loops.

I hope one of the experts can help me how to approach that task, any help is greatly appreciated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = [dict([*p.items(),
                ['colleagues', [q for q in input if p != q]]
               ]) for p in input]
```

You might be able to speed it up by using sets and `inputset - set(p)`.

The whole `dict([*p.items(), [k, v]])` is kind of a hack to make a new dict with an extra key-value pair without having to use statements. It is pretty much equivalent to `dict_with_new_pair(p, k, v)` given:

```
def dict_with_new_pair(d, k, v):
    from copy import copy
    c = copy(d)
    c[k] = v
    return c
```

EDIT: As you said, both `p` and `q` are elements of `input`. The expression parses like this: For every person `p` in `input`, enrich it with key `colleagues`, whose value will be the all persons `q` in `input` that are not `p` (and collect the list of all such enriched `p` into a new list `output`).

Comment: Amazing, this solved my problem, thank you! I'm wondering how the code works.. The list comprehension iterates through the dictionaries of the input list, and you explained what dict([*p.items(), [k, v]]) does.  Could you explain the if condition and what p and q stand for? Both seem to be elements of input. Thanks again for your help !